# Must extending class have the same access level as the class it extends

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I want to extend a class that is declared *public class A*

It seems that if I want to create a *Class B* which extends class A, I must declare it with public modifier. Is it correct?
I will be happy to get an explanation why I can't make access level "stronger" when extending a class?

I encounter this problem when I tried to extends the following class:

```
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<VH extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

and when I extended **VH**, **RecyclerView.ViewHolder** with a class named :**MyViewHolder** that has private access I got a message saying: *'MyViewHolder has private access in ...'*

Comment: No, you can easily have a `public class A` but somewhere also have a `private class B extends A`.

Comment: Members can't have stronger access permissions than in the superclass. I'm guessing the message, whatever it is and wherever it is coming from, relates to a use of `MyViewHolder` not how it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code probably looks something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    ...
    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that `MyViewHolder` is only accessible in `MyAdapter`'s body, not in its declaration.  This can be worked around by making `MyViewHolder` package-private, so `MyAdapter`'s declaration can see it.

From the [Java 8 Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6):

> A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference type, or
> a constructor of a class type, is accessible only if the type is
> accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access:
>
> - [descriptions of public, protected, and package access]
> - Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level
>   class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or
>   constructor.